# docker tmpfs seems to have no effect on postgresql

Tags: django, postgresql, docker, tmpfs

I have a Postgres database inside a docker container against which I run django tests. I want to improve the speed of the tests. The easiest way to do this (it seems to me) is to move postgres data into tmpfs volume.

Here's what I did:

```
docker run --name my_tfmps_test -d -p 5432:5432 \
-e POSTGRES_USER=postgres \
-e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres \
-e POSTGRES_DB=my_database \
-e PGDATA=/var/lib/postgresql/data \
--tmpfs /var/lib/postgresql/data \
library/postgres
```

Because I specified `--tmpfs` I expect the tests run significantly faster. Unfortunately this is not the case. The speed of the tests remains exactly on the same level (give or take 5%).

My questions is: why did the speed of the tests did not change? And what can I do about it ?

Extra info:

- MacOS 10.13.6
- reference https://docs.docker.com/storage/tmpfs/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> My questions is: why did the speed of the tests did not change? And what can I do about it ?

If the table is so small that it already fits into ram, tmpfs doesn't gain you much except a few flushes to the disk. And, if that disk is an SSD it's not much at all. Typically you can make your testing suite go faster by turning off the [Durability Options](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/non-durability.html).